# Thermal gravitational waves vs thermal radiation

Tags: thermal-radiation, gravitational-waves

A body at temperature $T$ has both an electromagnetic emission spectrum and a gravitational emission spectrum, are there any temperatures or conditions where the gravitational one could be comparable in energy to the electromagnetic one? Or does the thermal electromagnetic radiation always dominate?

What does the "blackbody" gravitational radiation spectrum look like? Is there any formula I can use to compare? Or there is no canonical formula due to the problem of quantum gravity?

Comment: [This question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/89983/how-many-of-which-particles-are-in-hawking-radiation) may be of interest.