# What is the mechanism for neutrino emissions from a black hole

Tags: black-holes, neutrinos

In Black Holes and Time Warps, Kip Thorne describes a conference he and Stephen Hawking took in the 1970's where Hawking discussed black hole evaporation.  He discussed radiating gravitational waves and neutrino emissions as ways a BH can evaporate....

I do not understand the neutrino portion for several reasons.

1. Neutrinos are massive objects and therefore should not be able to escape the gravity of the BH
2. Neutrinos are made in nuclear reactions, as far as I know there are none in a BH, so how are they generated?
3. If they are generated outside the event horizon, how would they draw energy from the BH?
4. If they could absorb energy from the BH, how this be possible?  Nothing including energy can escape a BH.....

Thanks

Comment: Your question has in fact nothing to do with neutrinos as, to me, it seems you don't understand the evaporation of black holes. Why didn't you ask a question about the latter?

Comment: [How many of which particles are in Hawking radiation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/89983/how-many-of-which-particles-are-in-hawking-radiation)

Comment: Have a read through [An explanation of Hawking Radiation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/251385/an-explanation-of-hawking-radiation/252236#252236).